# Read first text line of an URL

Tags: java, url

I am trying to read the first line of a URL.
Then i want to use that as a string later in the code.
Anyone can help me?
I already tried it with

```
    public static String main(String[] args) {

    try {

        URL url = new URL("myurlhere");

        // read text returned by server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            return line;
        }
        in.close();

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;

}
```

I just can't get a string out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for your purpose:

```
try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://popofibo.com/pop/swaying-views-of-our-past/").get();
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
        for(Element p : paragraphs) {
          System.out.println(p.text());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

> It is indeed difficult to argue over the mainstream ideas of evolution of human civilizations...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from a file on the internet using a URL you should use URLConnection

here is a simple example:

```
    String string = "";
    try {
        URLConnection connection = new URL(
                "http://myurl.org/mypath/myfile")
                .openConnection();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            string += scanner.next() + " ";
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Do something with the string.
```

Comment: Hey linus, thanks for the reply but what should msg be?

Comment: @user3187533 oh sorry, I meant to do `string += scanner.next() + " ";`. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Hey linus, thanks! it worked, but it puts "ï»¿" in front of it. any idea how to remove this? EDIT: nevermind. i fixed it with substring(3)

Comment: Okay, but if you know what Charset you're trying to read you can always add a parameter, for instance `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream(), "<charset>"`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) is a list of charsets you might want to try.